# Is there a way of resetting a user's password in Realm Database

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I would like to be able to reset a user's password, in the case they have forgotten it. Is this possible using the Realm framework. As a natural extension to this problem, would is there a way of changing the user's password upon entering (correctly) their current password.

I am creating an iOS application in Swift.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you edit your answer and add your code please. How the password being set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Realm Mobile Platform, we provide `SyncUser.changePassword(_:, completion:)` and `SyncUser.changePassword(_:, forUserID:, completion:)` APIs.

https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#changing-passwords

We have not provided a convenient way to achieve "Forgot password?" feature currently, so you need implement such UI and workflow yourself.

> is there a way of changing the user's password upon entering (correctly) their current password.

You need to try logging in to see if the current password is correct.